# How to compute max input voltage for DC/DC LT3483

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter, inverter, input

I am trying to understand why, in the datasheet, the maximum input voltage of the [LT3483](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3483fc.pdf) changes.

In the features we have: "Wide Input Range: 2.5V to 16V". However, on the last page, we have an example:

[image: example]

Here the max. input voltage is 6 V, and output is -5 V.

Moreover, there is a different document:

[Demonstration circuit guide](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/dc801A.pdf)

And there are 2 circuit examples:

[image]

These have different maximum input voltages; 12 V for -15 V output, and 4.2 V for -8 V output.

How to compute the max. input voltage?

Is there some rule?

Or is it always 16 V, but in the datasheet it's smaller because of a typo (6 V = 16 V), and capacitors protection in the "Demonstration circuit guide"?

Comment: Welcome! Depends on your passive component selection. The IC can withstand at least 16 V. Please simulate it in LTspice and sweep the input voltage to wider than specified for one of the examples to find out.

Comment: So, the only problem is with passive elements? If I use passive components that have much higher voltage and current parameters than needed, I can safely use 16 V?

Comment: It’s not the passives themself but rather the situation they “program” the IC to operate in. Simulate it! It’s free.

Comment: I simulated and didn't find any difference between 5 V and 15 V for -5V output example. Not in output voltage, not in input current, etc. I think, in examples, they copied them from somewhere, where it matters (due to passive components or something else, not DC/DC performance specifically).  Because in the datasheet there is no info about operating voltages for different circuit configurations or output voltages. Thank you very much.

Comment: What about peak current?

Comment: For 5 V on the input, it is about 90 mA, for 15 V it is about 130 mA. So with higher voltage it works even better.

Comment: Peak current is limited to 200 mA, so there is decent margin at 130 mA. Perhaps peak current limitation of the inductor? Otherwise your comment is valid why they chose such a conservative rating on input voltage.

Comment: But, in efficiency graph, for any example, they show maximum of 60 mA.

Comment: Input? I’m talking peak switch and inductor current. You need to prove that node in LTspice.

Comment: Load. For input inductor peak current is 400 mA max. As it shown in datasheet. Saw like signal.

Comment: Datasheet said 200/400 mA. I didn’t dig deep enough to get what the 200 mA mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a distinction between the absolute maximum voltage limit (above which you can expect IC failure) and, the maximum operating voltage for a specific circuit configuration (above which the output voltage or load current cannot be guaranteed). These are two different things.

Comment: Ok, so input voltage in the examples shows range in which output parameters will be guaranteed.

How can I compute them myself? Or simulation is the only way? 

If I have - 10 V with specific topology for example.

In the -5 V example, input voltage can be higher than output.

In the -15 V, it should be lower.

Comment: @4a4ik correct. Simulation is always a good way and can either replace hand calculations or used with them. I don't follow the rest of your comment but, please [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why folk give free help.